# Is there a way to change the file path for an Rstudio project?

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I'm using GIT and I note that if I just move the whole folder (or rename it) in windows, that it breaks all the paths. I then end up in an infinite loop of trying to quit Rstudio and Rstudio unable to find the file path to save (or not save).

Is there a way to move the location of the project folder while keeping it still intact?

Sorry, let me make this clearer.

1. Start Rstudio and create a version-controlled project (I'm using GIT)
2. Realize that you put the project in the wrong folder of your computer
3. Move the project to the new folder by (a) moving the Rstudio and GIT files to another location using windows explorer. (breaking all the links) or (b) start a new project in the 'correct' location. (losing the versions of your edits).

Comment: So you're moving the location of the project while you have that project open?  Also how does this relate to git?  This seems to be RStudio project specific.

Comment: Thanks, @Dason. I hope my edit makes it a little clearer. It's not moving it wiht Rstudio open. I can also just move the files and open an 'existing' project in Rstudio. But it's the GIT part I can't figure out.

Comment: Too bad this is off-topic, I'm having a similar issue. Where should one ask this inside the SE environment, anyway?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio I wish I could tell you I've found a solution in the last months, but I still don't know how this is done! (And I still don't know where it would be considered on-topic.)

Comment: I know this is 2 years later, but it seems like RStudio now accommodates this. I moved the folder that a .Rproj file was enclosed in, and had no issues accessing the project (and all data structures) from the new location.

Comment: @Adam_G Was this a project with version control? Did you just move it in windows explorer?

Comment: i moved a new r project and renamed the .Rproj file to match the directory. the project seems to open fine in rstudio

Comment: I am a little disgruntled that the question is closed, because it _does_ describe the specific problem, and _including valid code is not possible_. The solution by @RayTarek works for me too, and deserves the status of an (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 3):

With RStudio closed, I moved the project folder (using Windows Explorer) to a new location. My RStudio project opened fine from there. I made an edit and pushed it to Github.

If you use the `here` package on Cran you won't have to update any links.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GitHub Desktop, it will detect that the project has been moved and allow you to locate (set) it to a different folder.